# Getting error while using python multiprocessing with s3 file download

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, python-multiprocessing

I am getting an error
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation`

I am trying to download s3 files from same bucket but with different prefixes in a parallel using multiprocessing Process api and with single s3 resource object.

```
s3_resource = object of s3 resource # all permissions are set up correctly

def download_parallel(s3_resource, bucket, prefix):
    # path = compute where to download using prefix
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, prefix).download_file(path)

import multiprocessing
p_list = []
for prefix in prefixes:
    p = mp.Process(target=download_parallel, args=(s3_resource, bucket, prefix))
    p.start()
    p_list.append(p)

for p in p_list:
    p.join()
```

Note:

1. All prefixes are present in s3 bucket. One of the prefix gets downloaded successfully while other fails.
2. It is not a permission related error.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: How expensive would it be to create a separate s3_resource in each thread rather than creating it once and passing it as an argument.  It is possible that there is some information being lost when it is pickled and then unpickled.

Comment: Boto3 client objects are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to download all the files to the same folder locally, this will work. Paste it into a .py file and run from the command prompt. Others may be able to find a more efficient way, but this works.

Essentially, I build the lists first - list of keys to download and the list of local full file paths, then send it all to multiprocessing function.

```
import boto3
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def get_files_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
        keys_list.extend(keys)
    if prefix in keys_list:
        keys_list.remove(prefix)
    return keys_list

def download_from_s3(bucket, key, fullpath):
    r = s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, fullpath)


def download_multiprocess(bucket, keys_list, paths, num_proc=4):
    with Pool(num_proc) as pool:
        r = pool.starmap(download_from_s3, zip(repeat(bucket), keys_list, paths), 15)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_proc = os.cpu_count()

    bucket = 'mybucket'
    path = 'C:/my/full/path/'
    prefixes = ['prefix/one/', 'another/prefix/here/']

    keyslist = []
    paths = []
    for prefix in prefixes:
        keyslist.extend(get_files_from_prefix(bucket, prefix))
    for k in keyslist:
        paths.append(path + k.split('/')[-1])
    print(paths)
    print(keyslist)

    download_multiprocess(bucket, keyslist, paths, num_proc=4)
```